# xml issue incorporating byte array

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

hello i use a form of message parsing in which i write fields into a buffered stream, and then extract a byte array repesantaition of that stream

```
MyMessage _message = new MyMessage("me","you",MessageType.peer_message,4252422) ;
// in the constructor String sender,String receiver,MessageType(enumaraition) m_type,Int32 id 

byte [] buffer = myEncoder.encode(message) ;
```

now when i pass this to myDecoder it decodes it in the same metter and it works great !
how i do that is not the issue

my issue is that in some cases of misscommunicaition i need to store the byte[] array (buffer) for farther use , and i'm trying to do that in an xmlDocumant under a tag
 HERE IN THE INNER TEXT IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO SAVE THAT ARRAY OF BYTES

ive tryed --> 
`utf8Encoding.Ascii.getString(buffer)` which save some kind of repsantaition
but it changes values of field wich are not strings... when i take it out by using

```
utf8Encoding.Ascii.getBytes(packet_node.innerText) ;
```

1)THE QUESTION IS HOW WOULD U GO ABOUT SAVING THAT BYTE ARRAY TO A XMLNODE
2)i've also tried just writing the fields one by one in each tag

```
 <Packet>
      <sender>me</sender>
      <receiver>him</receiver>
      <MessageType> ..?? how would  i represent a byte as a string ? </MessageType> 
      <Id> 4252353523 </Id> here i have no problem but i still would have to always prase the value back and forth in other uses from int to string ..

</Packet>
```

3) so my conclusion is to serialize the byte array to an xmldocument .. just that i don't want it to be a document but just one node in an existing document

Comment: Jeff M has the truth of it suggesting base-64; for information on why: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/03/binary-data-and-strings.html

Answer (score 4):

Encode it as a base-64 string.  Just remember to decode it when you read it back.

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
```

Comment: To expand ... not all byte streams will contain valid UTF-8 encodings.  You say it changes values which are not strings, but you're asking it to treat the entire buffer as if it were a single UTF-8 encoded string. If you were to create an encoder by calling new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, true), and then call the GetBytes() method on that encoder, you may get an exception, as the second param causes it to throw if the byte array is not a valid UTF8 encoding.